# How to display only the second purchase made per account

Tags: mysql

I have a transactions table which has shows various transactions made by several accounts. Some make only one, others more than that. At the moment the SQL I have prints out the first purchase of each account but i need it to print out the second made by each account

```
SELECT account_id
     , purchase_date as second_purchase
     , amount as second_purchase_amount
FROM Transactions t
WHERE purchase_date NOT IN (SELECT MIN(purchase_date)
                            FROM Transactions m
                            )
GROUP BY account_id
HAVING purchase_date = MIN(purchase_date);
```

What needs to change that the second purchase date and amount are chosen? I tried adding in a count for the account_id but it was giving me the wrong value.

Comment: Can you add some sample table data and the expected result? (As well formatted text.)

Comment: just curious. Do you want "2nd" purchase of "latest" purchase. A person can have eg 4 purchases. So ... not sure if you still want the 2nd one or the 4th one. If only the latets one, use this statement `WHERE purchase_date IN (SELECT MAX(...` as your where clause would do the job I think.

Comment: The second purchase overall, ie they have 4 purchases, just the second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables to assign row numbers and get the 2nd purchase.

```
SELECT account_id,purchase_Date,amount 
FROM (
     SELECT account_id
         ,purchase_date
         ,amount
         --, @rn:=IF(account_id=@a_id and @pdate <> purchase_date,@rn+1,1) as rnum
         ,case when account_id=@a_id and @pdate <> purchase_date then @rn:=@rn+1
               when account_id=@a_id and @pdate=purchase_date then @rn:=@rn
          else @rn:=1 end as rnum
         , @pdate:=purchase_date
         , @a_id:=account_id
     FROM Transactions t
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0,@a_id:=-1,@pdate:='') r
     ORDER BY account_id, purchase_date
    ) x 
WHERE rnum=2
```

Explanation of how it works:

- `@rn:=0,@a_id:=-1,@pdate:=''` - Declare 3 variables and initialize them, @rn for assigning the row numbers, @a_id to hold the account_id and @pdate to hold the purchase_date.
- For the first row (ordered by account_id and purchase_date), account_id and @a_id, @pdate and purchase_date will be compared. As they wouldn't be equal, the `when` conditions fail and the `else` part would assign @rn=1. Also, the variable assignment happens after this. @aid and @pdate would be updated to current row's values. For the second row, if they are the same account and on a different date the first `when` condition will be executed and the @rn will be incremented by 1. If there are ties the second `when` condition would be executed and the @rn remains the same. You can run the inner query to check how the variables are assigned.

Comment: This works perfectly, ty! But i must admit, I have basic sql skills and dont really understand this. Is there an easier way to do this? If not I can try and look up this answer in more detail to understand

Comment: sure..i will explain how it works..can there be more than one purchase on the same date for an account?

Comment: For the data I have, there isnt any made by the same account on the same day

Comment: sure..i modified the query so the multiple rows (if they exist) on a given date would be returned.

Comment: could you please explain the cross join line? this is the first time ive come across it and looking it up I still dont understand it, i thought it would just be used in the case of more than one table

Comment: The result of `SELECT @rn:=0,@a_id:=-1,@pdate:=''` would be one row and when it is cross joined to the table, the variables would be available for use on all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Number the rows and choose RowNumber = 2

```
select *
from (
    select
         @rn := case when @account_id = account_id then @rn + 1 else @rn := 1 end as RowNumber,
         @account_id := account_id as account_id, 
         purchase_date
    from 
        (select @rn := 1) x,
        (select @acount_id :=account_id as account_id, purchase_date 
         from Transactions 
         order by account_id, purchase_date)  y
     ) z
where RowNumber = 2;
```

Comment: this returns the second purchase made for the dataset, what I need is to be able to return the second purchase made by each account